# Laravel debugger - enable/disable depending on IP address while caching implemented

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

We need to **eneble/disable Laravel debugbar depending on IP address**. It works if we clear/disable the caching.

But it does not work when caching enabled. here is my code

```
//Enabling DEBUGBAR in Production Only for developers
if(in_array($request->ip(), [ip addresses])) {
    config(['app.debug' => true]);
}
```

**.env**

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

We are using configuration and route caching. What would be the best way to achieve this?

> Laravel version - **5.4**
>
> Debugbar version - **2.2**

Comment: Where's this code?

Comment: The code is added already. Checking with `in_array`.

Comment: I mean where did you add this code in your app

Comment: AppServiceProvider.php

Comment: Your service provider shouldn't be affected by route or config caching.  Sounds like something else is going on

Comment: I am not sure. I have tried in MiddleWare also.

Comment: Did you verify your config value or are you only  looking 
at the debugbar?  My assumption is debugbar is checking your config value before you're setting it to true.

Comment: Hope it would help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905292/laravel-debugger-enable-disable-depending-on-ip-address-while-caching-implemen/54983089#54983089

Comment: Clear cache if needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905292/laravel-debugger-enable-disable-depending-on-ip-address-while-caching-implemen/54983089#54983089

Comment: I am already doing that. But it is not working with cache.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Debugger has functionality to enable/disable it at runtime :

```
\Debugbar::enable();
\Debugbar::disable();
```

> If you want to use the debugbar in production, disable in the config and only enable when needed.

So you can do :

```
if(in_array($request->ip(), [ip addresses])) {
    \Debugbar::enable();
    // Forcing the cache to be cleared
    // Not recommended but if and only if required
    \Artisan::call('cache:clear');
}
```

Please check [documentation](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) for more  help.

Comment: Yup, it worked. I had a specific client where I wanted to debug, I used user ID instead of IP. But if it goes into the if condition then I suppose it should work

Comment: Do you have any custom caching layer or you are using laravel's default caching?

Comment: Default caching.

Comment: Updated my answer with one trick if that helps. I am not sure why it is not working but see if the artisan clear cache works for you?

Comment: Laravel quickly builds back cache so I dont think the ripple effect will be cascaded for long time.

Comment: `cache:clear` clears your cache stores (like Cache::put, Cache::get).  There's no cache in Laravel that hits the service providers.

Comment: `\Artisan::call('cache:clear');` getting error for maximum execution time.

Comment: One thing to remember - if any visits from those IPs, the whole cache will be regenerated. which may cost some speed.

Comment: @SougataBose you can store a flag in session that debugger is enabled with the IP address as the key. So in next request if it's already enabled, you can skip the clearing cache step.

Comment: @MihirBhende No problem with cleaning the cache but once the debugbar is enabled in cache it will be enabled for all untill it is not disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Debugbar` library so this library will be loaded before your route or controller loaded, so better you have to bootstrap your stuffs before the library loaded. Then we can bootstrap our custom configuration in the `AppServiceProvider` class.

Service providers are the central place of all Laravel application bootstrapping.

**Simple Method**: 
Change the file `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` class according to the below code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Request;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // You can also clear cache if needed Artisan::call('cache:clear');
        if(in_array(Request::ip(), ['127.0.0.1'])) {
            config(['app.debug' => true]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: It would work only if cache is not enaqbled for configs.